# How can I set properties on multiple clones in a generic list after instantiation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't understand why this does not work:

```
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x,0,y);
TerrainTiles.Add(Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/TerrainTile"), pos, Quaternion.identity) as TerrainTile);
Debug.Log("List items: " + TerrainTiles.Count.ToString());
TerrainTiles[TerrainTiles.Count - 1].xPosition = x;
```

Running the `Debug.Log` shows that the list items are being created but when I try to reference any of them as in the last line of code above I am getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: TerrainTiles is a class from what package? Because it sure isn't part of base Unity's components. If it's from Terrain Tile Editor, you're unlikely to get many people who own a $50 package.

Comment: TerrainTiles is a prefab that I have created within Unity. I am trying to instantiate clones of the prefab dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the product you are using but it appears that `TerrainTiles` is a collection with one `null` value. If so, `.Count` will still return a number. Check your paths. Is `Resources.Load()` supposed to load an entire directory?

Try this:

```
TerrainTile tile;

if((tile = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/TerrainTile"), pos, Quaternion.identity) as TerrainTile) != null){
    TerrainTiles.Add(tile);
}
```

Comment: While I agree that this is good practice, this unfortunately does not solve the problem. Nevertheless, I am modifying my code to make this check.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure your prefab is accesible with a path containing a 'Resources' folder as stated in the documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.html

Secondly, you cannot load an entire directory, you can only load a particular resource one at a time. So here "Prefabs/TerrainTile" should refer to a file named TerrainTile.prefab (or another extension).

And as @drankin2112 already pointed out, it is safer to check the reference before adding it to the list (or any collection):

```
TerrainTile tile;
tile = Resources.Load("Prefabs/TerrainTile", typeof(TerrainTile)) as TerrainTile);
// Check whether resource exists
if (tile != null)
{
    tile = Instantiate(tile, pos, Quaternion.Identity) as TerrainTile;
    // Check whether instantiation worked
    if (tile != null)
    {
        tileList.Add(tile);
    }
}
```

Comment: The prefab is accessible with the "Resources" directory residing just beneath the "Assets" directory in the project. Furthermore, I know that the clones are being instantiated successfully because when I remove the very last line of code from my first post all of the instances appear in the scene in both the Hierarchy panel and in the scene view.

I am not attempting to load the entire directory. However, I am trying to clone one prefab many times and set distinct properties for each clone instance.

Comment: What kind of collection is TerrainTiles? Is it a list, a set?
Did you try to add a breakpoint after the Add method to see what the collection contains at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up solving the problem:

```
    TerrainTiles.Add(Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/TerrainTile", typeof(TerrainTile)), pos, Quaternion.identity) as TerrainTile);
```

Thank all of you for your advice and assistance.